# Instagram - Identifying a user by some sort of uuid (Java)

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram seems to have something called pk, i would think this is some sort od uuid for each user but it's only long and instagram has millions of users i dont think that's it. Is there any way to get a user's id or to somehow identify him even when he changes his username?
I've looked around and there isn't really a straight answer on what pk is or how to do this.

I am using this library if it matters: https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a reference for where `pk` is coming from?

Comment: From github it looks like its this. however now that i think about it, it might just be from the library itself.
https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j/blob/2a47054f0ec3485e6a6dd7f92096a298eff47812/src/main/java/com/github/instagram4j/instagram4j/models/user/Profile.java#L14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library in question, however conceptually a `long` is more than enough to cover all the Instagram users.

In fact, a long can represent 2<sup>64</sup> numbers, which assuming that there are 7.9 billion people in the word, is a massive 2335030895 times the entire population.

Answer (score 0):

If you would simply inspect the web browser you will find the user id attached to each profile, this id doesn't change even if a user changes their username.

This same id is used to make different calls like following a user or unfollow. I use my own automation scripts and it works fine using it.